# How to calculate percentage with a SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql

i have two sql tables i want to compare two  tables ..comparing two tables is done now what i want is how many records are matched and not matched in the form of percentage .is it possible to write a query in sql to get percentage?
 and here is my tables

```
  src_table

----------------------------------------------------------------
src_table
----------------------------------------------------------------
1
2
3
a
b
c
a@
b@
c@
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

and tgt_table is

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
tgt_data
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1
4
5
a
e
f
a@
e@
f@
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and now i want matched data and unmatched in the form of percentage is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wish to calculate the percentage over the table `tgt_data`.
If this is not the case, just exchange the table names below.

The query depends on the capabilities of your SQL product.
If it cannot handle complex expressions with sub-queries, you will need
to break the expression into multiple statements.

The expression you would like to calculate is:

```
(select count(*) * 100 from tgt_data t where exists
  (select * from src_table where src_col = t.tgt_col))
/
(select count(*) from tgt_data)
```

If you need to formulate it as one SELECT statement, this is an alternate formulation:

```
select  
(select count(*) * 100 from tgt_data t where exists
  (select * from src_table where src_col = t.tgt_col))
/ count(*)
from tgt_data
```

If your product calculates this in integer arithmetic, and you would like
the result in decimal, then replace `100` by `100.0` above.